# Combining items in an rss feed in yahoo pipes to create a summary or digest feed

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I need a yahoo pipe design that allows me to pull the field items from:
http://www.kayak.com/h/rss/buzzto?code=RTB&mc=USD&max=750

And turn them into a digest post.

For example:
Instead of 10 posts of different flight options, a new feed is created that merges the last 2 days worth of feed items into 1 new "readers digest" or summary style feed.

Right now it's:

item 1: LON to RTB $1,212 Dec 15 - Jan 19 on Multiple Airlines found 1 day ago

item 2: PBI to RTB $530 Dec 16 - Jan 19 on United found 1 day ago

item 3: NYC to RTB $697 Dec 15 - Jan 18 on Multiple Airlines found 1 day ago

item 4: JFK to RTB $815 Dec 14 - Jan 18 on Taca Intl Air found 1 day ago

Need it to be:

item 1:

LON to RTB $1,212 Dec 15 - Jan 19 on Multiple Airlines found 1 day ago

PBI to RTB $530 Dec 16 - Jan 19 on United found 1 day ago

NYC to RTB $697 Dec 15 - Jan 18 on Multiple Airlines found 1 day ago

JFK to RTB $815 Dec 14 - Jan 18 on Taca Intl Air found 1 day ago